# Copy files from Android's Gdx.files.local() folder to developing machine

Tags: java, android, file, libgdx, storage

LibGDX: I have game-data files created at runtime for debugging purposes (a replay system). The files are stored in `Gdx.files.local()` whether on desktop or android. Now I want to copy the ones that were created on android so I can debug them on desktop.

Running `Gdx.files.getLocalStoragePath()` on android returns `/data/user/0/com.[my domain].[my app]/files/`. Using Windows Explorer I do not see my app's folder in `/data/user/0`, or anything else for that matter. So private storage indeed it is, but how nonetheless can I get hold of these files, without root if possible?

The solution may be manual copy or in code, whatever works. Just to note, the file names are unknown without seeing the files first. They were named using current date-time. The extension is known, though.

**EDIT**

I discovered Android Studio's Device File Explorer. I connected my device, tried to see inside my app folder and app data folder, both showing 'Operation not permitted'.

So to put the question in simpler words, is rooting the phone really the only way for ***developers*** to see the files created by their apps?

Or is there a magical gate somewhere known only to select few zen masters who guard the secret through the generations? Because I sure ain't finding it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is a way to write changes in the system file without having root access but you can read them. According to this [Blog,](https://forums.androidcentral.com/software-development-hacking/612977-i-can-access-root-folders-without-rooting.html) You can access those files and put it in your desktop. You can download RAR app from [googleplay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rarlab.rar&hl=en).

Comment: I actually have RAR, it didn't occur to me to try it. But still, 'Show Hidden Files' enabled and I see the root and still don't see my files. BTW not sure what you meant by write changes in the system file. I do write and read these files from within my app. I just want to copy them to desktop.

Comment: Go the directory where your files are and enable show hidden files when connected to desktop via usb(In windows, Go to folder options and untick every hide options and In Linux, Press Ctrl+L)

Comment: Thing is I don't see my app data folder either, not just the files. I went to the parent folder where my app data folder is supposed to be (/data/user/0), unticked all hide options - no change.